# Set time zone on one rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to set the time zone on one rspec test in this way:

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Hawaii')
Time.stub(:now) { Time.now.in_time_zone(zone) }
```

This gives me a stack level too deep error, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Hawaii')
Time.stub(:now){ Time.new.in_time_zone(zone) }
```

I am not sure, but it seems like stubbing `now` and then calling `Time.now` in block is causing stack level too deep error.

Comment: Sweet, that was it.  I was trying to change the time zone on Delorean.time_travel_to(1.days.ago).  I thought by stubbing Time.now I could change the time zone because time_travel_to uses Time.now.  This didn't work after your fix got it running.  You don't happen to have an idea off the top of your head do you?

Comment: I am sorry, I never used Delorean for mocking time in my specs. By the way, [Delorean](https://github.com/bebanjo/delorean) looks outdated, did you consider using [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) instead?

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on an old project.  I was trying to avoid using a different gem for one test but I'll probably have to try it.  I have one test that fails after 4:00 p.m. when tests run on Semaphore because the server uses UTC.  It's really annoying and I want to fix it.

Comment: I can recommend these railscasts. 1: http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised 2: http://railscasts.com/episodes/276-testing-time-web-requests But then I think you might have already known about them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you would like to follow specific time each time in your test

```
Time.stub(:now).and_return(Time.mktime(2017,01,23,11,00,00).gmtime)
```